# Does anyone know the simple command line to draw a vertical dashed line on a plot at a specific x-value on an x-y plot in SciDraw?

Tags: scidraw

The scripting below works to draw a vertical line at x=1.58 but rather brute force method.

```
  FigGraphics[
  Plot[y = 0 + 10^5 (x - 1.58), {x, 1.58, 1.5801}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, 
     Dashed}]];
```

Comment: This site is only for *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have SciDraw (which I assume is a Mathematica package) installed, so I'll just do a simple plot to demonstrate the use of the option Epilog:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}, 
 Epilog -> {Dashed, Line[{{1.58, 0}, {1.58, 1}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, SciDraw is an add-in for MM. I can't use Epilog as I am not adding it to an existing Plot command unless I use Plot to draw the line as above, in which case it is redundant.

Comment: Thank you in any case for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. It's not completely clear what you're trying to do - maybe some more context in your question would help people come up with a better solution. At the moment, the only other option I can come up with is to use the Drawing Tools, in the Graphics menu (or ctrl-D), which can be used to manually edit Graphics objects.

Comment: A command to draw a line in SciDraw is:

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind - though it'd probably be best to add it to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

This may be useful for other users of SciDraw. The code below runs with SciDraw package within Mathematica. I've found that I can specify under "SetOptions" SciDraw command for a dashed line to be the drawn by the command "FigRule" (here a vertical line at x= 1.58). (The plot data and plot commands have been removed for clarity)

````
Needs["SciDraw`"];
PrintSciDrawSplash[];
DefineStyle["Figure",
 {
  FigurePanel -> {
    ShowFrameLabel -> {True, True},
    FontFamily -> "Ariel Black",
    FontSize -> 7,
    XPlotRange -> {0, 2},
    XExtendRange -> 0.05,
    XFrameLabel -> "[001] stress (\[InvisiblePrefixScriptBase]kbar)",
    XFrameLabelPosition -> 0.5,
    YPlotRange -> {-0.1, 2},
    YFrameLabel -> "Negative replicas of phonon spectra",
    YFrameLabelPosition -> 0.50,
    YTicks -> LinTicks[0, 1, 0.5, 2], FontSize -> 7
    }
  }
 ]

Figure[
 FigurePanel[
  {
   SetOptions[FigRule, LineDashing -> 4],  
   FigRule[Vertical, 1.58, All] 
   
   }
  ],
 
 CanvasUnits -> Centimeter, CanvasMargin -> 1, 
 CanvasSize -> {6.5, 3.5}, Style -> "Figure"]

```
````